# Would I be considered a Masters degree holder right after my course completion?

Tags: masters, graduation

I am currently a MS student looking forward to complete all of my courses by December 2016.

Will I be recognized as a Masters degree holder right after December 2016 so that my employers can file for H1B as soon as possible after April 1st of 2017?

Or do I have to wait till my Graduate Commencement Ceremony to be recognized as a degree holder, which is not till May of 2017?

Comment: Have you asked your graduate office about whether they can write a letter of certification once you are finished in December, stating that you have completed all degree requirements and that your degree will be conferred in May?

Comment: No , I have not. But I will do so as you indicated . Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date on which you finish courses is not necessarily the date when you earn the degree, nor is the date of the commencement ceremony.

What matters is the date on which the degree is *conferred* by the university. If you're not sure what that date is, ask the registrar's office.

In some cases if the degree conferral date for students completing their coursework in December/January is after the H1B deadline, the registrar may have some kind of special arrangement (see [this example from Stanford](https://registrar.stanford.edu/students/certifications-and-verifications/h-1b-degree-certification-letter-information-and)), which they'll tell you about if you ask.

Comment: I will right away ask my registrar's office. Thank you for the direction.

Comment: My universities have always offered a letter confirming the right to graduate, stating basically that everything is finished and we're just waiting for the actual ceremony, for exactly this type of situation. Check what your graduation office also offers.

Comment: My university used to confer degrees at the end of the fall, spring, and summer terms.  Years ago, degrees were only conferered only at the end of the spring term.  In the past students could request a letter from the college confirming that they'd met requirements for the degree although the degree had not yet been confered, but some employers wouldn't accept this.  We now confer degrees at the end of each month, so that graduate students who complete their thesis defense can graduate almost immediately.